# How to present data in a tree like table in UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have data which is expected to be displayed in a structured table. It is expected that the table can be opened and collapsed on two levels allowing
you to drill down in the data.

Example: Cities World Wide

When the table is loaded it should be displayed like this:

    `Area      |     Country    |     Name    | Population  | ... 
--------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+----
Europe        |                |             |             | 
North America |                |             |             | 
...           |                |             |             |`

when I click on "Europe" the second level is shown:

    `Area      |     Country    |     Name    | Population  | ... 
--------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+-----
Europe        |                |             |             | 
              | Germany        |             |             | 
              | Czech Republic |             |             | 
North America |                |             |             | 
...           |                |             |             |`

When I now click on "Germany" the third level containing the actual city data is shown:

    `Area      |     Country    |     Name    | Population  | ... 
--------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+-----
Europe        |                |             |             | 
              | Germany        |             |             | 
              |                | Berlin      | 4 Million   | ...
              |                | Leipzig     | 0.5 Million | ...
              | Czech Republic |             |             | 
North America |                |             |             | 
...           |                |             |             |`

How can I achieve a drill down in a tree like structure like shown in this example in UI5?

Since one of the requirement is to also to see and compare the data at once I believe a table control would be best but I don't know how to bring in this drill down behavior.

Mobile support is not required. The person using this will be a data analyst working on a big screen.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question I came up with the search phrase "ui5 tree table" and voila:
https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/ui-components/tree-table/

This is what I was looking for.